# How to access an entire table row based on annotation with Max()

Tags: python, django, orm, django-annotate

I have a model that stores the cover images for different magazines (publications).

In a simplified version it looks like this

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PublicationIssue(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, null=False)
    issue_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In SQL I can execute something like this:

```
select 
publication_id, 
max(issue_number) current_issue, 
cover_image 
from conditionalsum_publicationissue 
group by publication_id
```

This looks for the max issue number for a publication and easily gives me the current issue number and the associated cover image. The output looks something like this:

```
publication_id   current_issue   cover_image
1                12              ae43fb33.jpg
2                26              445fbb45.jpg
3                213             db8489e3.jpg
```

---

I know I can use rawsql in a Django query, but I wanted to see if there are solutions that avoid this.

It's easy enough to get the current issue:

```
PublicationIssue.objects. \
values('publication_id'). \
annotate(current_issue=Max('issue_number'))
```

This returns the publication_id with the current_issue. But this look like a dead end as far as adding the cover_image.

Adding 'cover_image' to the values clause does not work and any further annotation will similarly expand the queryset in ways incorrect for my purposes. I have attempted going with a subquery, but that is getting fairly long and complicated for a relatively simple SQL statement.

In summary: my question is how do I translate

```
select 
publication_id, 
max(issue_number) current_issue, 
cover_image 
from conditionalsum_publicationissue 
group by publication_id
```

- with the challenge being the cover_image field - into a Django query without using rawsql?